# PCA across repeated measures conditions

Tags: r, python, pca

I have a dataset of 80 individuals, 8 measurements across 3 different conditions (not time point).

Some sources tell me I should use multiple factor analysis, while other sources tell me I should use PCA separately and compare the relative contribution of each factor.

I was wondering which one to use.

If possible, solutions in R/python would be greatly appreciated.